# Not able to copy int array into struct address of given struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, copy

```
struct media{
     uint32_t addressOfPtr; 
 };
```

Some error somewhere, but I am not able to see it.

```
printf(" > %x",  ((uint8_t*) mediaObject2->addressOfPtr)[i]);
```

is not print

```
uint8_t message[SIZE_MAX];

for (i=0;i<SIZE_MAX;i++) {
    message[i] = i+1;
    printf(" > %x",  message[i]);
}

uint8_t *msg_Ptr;
msg_Ptr = malloc(SIZE_MAX*sizeof(uint8_t));
memcpy(msg_Ptr, &message, SIZE_MAX);

printf("\n####################\n");

for (i=0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)  // message fixed at length 10
    printf(" > %x",  msg_Ptr[i]);

printf("\n");

struct media *mediaObject2;
(mediaObject2->addressOfPtr) = malloc(SIZE_MAX*sizeof(uint8_t));
(mediaObject2->addressOfPtr) = (uint32_t) msg_Ptr;
printf("\n####################\n"); // Last stop
//printf(">>>> %x ", mediaObject2->addressOfPtr);

printf("\n");
for (i=0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)  // message fixed at length 10
    printf(" > %x",  ((uint8_t*) mediaObject2->addressOfPtr)[i]);

printf("\n");
```

Comment: And should use a different name `SIZE_MAX` from being used in `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: you, are right. I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part:

```
struct media *mediaObject2;
(mediaObject2->addressOfPtr) = malloc(SIZE_MAX*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

you are using uninitialized pointer `mediaObject2`, which invokes an *undefined behavior*.

You need to either dynamically allocate memory for `struct media` or yet even better: use a variable with automatic storage duration here:

```
struct media mediaObject2;
mediaObject2.addressOfPtr = malloc(SIZE_MAX*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

---

Side note: If `struct media` was supposed to hold a pointer to an array of `uint8_t`, you should have declare this member as `uint8_t *data` or if the type is going to vary but it will be a pointer still, then `void* dataPtr` at least... anything is better than `uint32_t addressOfPtr;`.

Comment: excellent. @LihO.

On a further question.


how do I pass it to a function, say:

void functionB (void* mediaObject) 

and pass the struct back to uint8_t message[SIZE_MAX]?

Comment: @UrsaMajor: `functionB(&mediaObject2)`... you might consider spending more time reading some books or other relevant materials.

Comment: I did that, but it is not able to reload within the function to the uint8_t message[].